# Validating DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input HTML elements which I want to validate whether they are filled up or not. Basically, they are mandatory. I am doing something like this:

```
    var displayNames new Array();
    displayNames[0] = "Name";
    displayNames[1] = "Address";
    displayNames[2] = "Age";

function validForm() {
    var Name = document.getElementById(txtName).value;
    if(!Name) {
      alert(displayName[0] is required);
    }}
```

How should I make the validations easy in JS?

Comment: Two things to remember with validation: 1) It should happen on the server as well as the client (I'm sure you have this covered already), and 2) it should be as little of an annoyance as possible. `alert` messages are really obtrusive; consider disabling the submit button until the data is entered correctly, or show a small red `div` that warns the user that data has been entered incorrectly (without messing up the form's focus).

Comment: Yeah, but I am building an iPad app, where I want to show the missing fields in a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I make the validations easy in JS?

It depends.  Are they all strings?  Or can some be numbers?  Or some in need of a regex (like an email address)?  Heck, can some even be an empty string or blank?

If we are talking about less than 12 fields, then I would consider rolling my own validation.  However, if we are talking a lot of fields spread across multiple pages and projects then I would consider using the a validation plugin such as http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Combination of Numbers, Strings and Date. And yeah, some of them can be empty too.

Comment: Okay, I have less than 12 fields. And also, the link that you posted. Whether it hold intra-dependencies between DOM elements too? Like if I check 1. CheckBox1 then TextBox1 should be checked. Something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: you can add validation rules for various dom elements: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules